# How to put a header and footer in Rails with gem htmltoword?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ms-word

I have read the documentation of the gem, but do not see as putting a header or footer.

This is my first code:

```
format.docx {
  render docx: "path_to/file.docx",
  filename: "name_file-#{Time.now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}"
}
```

And my **"path_to/file.docx.haml"**:

```
%html
  %head
  %body
    %header
      [..]
    %content
      %table[..]
      %h1 [..]
      %p [..]
    %footer
      %p
      %ul
        %li
      [..]
```

And my other code is:

```
format.docx {
  render docx: "path_to/file.docx",
  filename: "Proforma-#{Time.now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}",
  header: { 
    :content => render_to_string({ template: 'path_to/header' })
  },
  footer: { 
    :content => render_to_string({ template: 'path_to/footer' })
  }
}
```

And my **"path_to/file.docx.haml"** only have the `%content` tag.

Then I have my other templates: **"path_to/header.haml"**, **"path_to/footer.haml"**.

But neither one works for me .
How could generate a word with header and footer correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This gem currently does not support this feature (neither header nor footer). See this thread [here](https://github.com/nickfrandsen/htmltoword/issues/10)

Comment: What gem recommend me to generate a word ?